# Execute python script with parameters in php

Tags: php, python, mysql, cgi

I have a php script which searches a mySQL database and returns all of its instances. I would like to use this instance data (string, string, string, list of lists of (string, string, string, string)) as parameter for a python script.

so how do i pass all this info to my python script? I know i use exec to execute the script, but how i do include the list of lists as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

you cant well not exactly

you can use redirection to send text to the script

```
exec("something.py < inputstuff.txt");
```

or you can pass an argument list

```
exec("something.py arg1 arg2 arg3");
```

you could pass it in as a string representation and eval it inside the script or something
if you use redirection the data should be available from sys.stdin  if you pass it as an arg list the data should be available via sys.argv

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $list = array('arg1', 'arg2');
    exec(sprintf('python script.py %s', escapeshellarg(implode(' ', $list)));
```

Then just use argparse: http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse.